# Access/update database with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, database, ajax, javascript

**Goal:** Update wpdb each time a user clicks on a specific button.

Every time a user clicks on a button, I need jQuery to run a function that will update my wordpress database. As far as I understand, this must be done through an AJAX request sent to a php file residing on the server. [This article](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) seems to address my issue, but I am having trouble interpreting exactly what it is I need to do.

A couple of my questions are as follows:

1. I will need a php file that will be called from the jQuery function, but where should that file be housed? I believe it should be at http:mysite.com/phpfile.php, but how can I get the file to be housed at that location?
2. What exactly should this php file consist of?

If someone is able to give me the steps needed to accomplish this goal, I would be forever grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API instead? You want to avoid having a PHP file you ping, it has maintenance, security, and other issues related to it

Comment: @TomJNowell I was under the impression that you could not change the db through the API. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @TomJNowell It looks like the API only has the ability to change Wordpress' core tables. I have a custom table that I'm attempting to access. Could I accomplish that through a custom API endpoint?

Comment: You can add custom endpoints with the `register_endpoint` function

Comment: @TomJNowell Can't this option cause security issues? Updating DB with jQuery?

Comment: @JackJohansson having a PHP file in your plugin or theme you ping directly can be a big security problem, and it's not how things work in WP themes and plugins. REST API endpoints are inherently more secure. I would note that it's the endpoint that changes the DB, not jQuery

Comment: @TomJNowell the API was a much simpler solution. Thanks so much! It works like a charm. If anyone has concerns regarding the security of this strategy, I'd love to hear it, but for now, I'll stick with this.